# ADLA AUs assigned for JSON files

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a custom Extractor with **AtomicFileProcessing set to false**. It extracts a large no of JSON files (each line in the file is a JSON document) and output two files with successful and failed requests, both of them contains the json rows (AUs allocated more than 1 to extract the files). Problem is when I use the same extractor to extract the outputted files in first step with more than one AU, it fails with the error, **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0**.

If I assign 1 AU on Azure or run this locally with AU set to more than 1, it successfully processes the data. Is this behavior because of more AU provided to process a single JSON file and since the file is in non-splittable format, it can't be parallelized?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this problem converting your json file to Jsonlines.

http://jsonlines.org/examples/

Then you need to read the file using text extractor and use JsonFunctions available on `Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats`
to read the json.

That transformation will make your file splittable and you can parallelized it!